Today, do we celebrate anniversaries of events that happened in time of Julian calendar, on Julian date or at corresponding Gregorian date?
Today do we celebrate anniversaries of events that happened in time of Julian calendar, on the Julian date or at the corresponding Gregorian date?
Do historians write the dates of scientific works in Julian dates or on the corresponding Gregorian dates?
example:
Lets say some book/theory is published 5.8.1724.(Julian), is today anniversary of book/theory 5.8. or 16.8.(corresponding Gergorian)?

Why would there be an answer to this question? Why wouldn't different people celebrate differently?   Is there a pan governmental body of which I'm unaware  that controls how we celebrate anniversaries?   Heck the US celebrates a decision that took place on 2 July on 4 July.... And we switched almost all our holidays to Monday. Let's talk "President's Day"?  The title question and first question are impossible to answer. The second question is slightly more answerable, but I suspect it depends on what is more useful. to the analytical technique in use.

@MCW
Technically you cant say "today is 300th anniversary of that event" if you take Julian date, because then math is not correct.  From 10.4.1724(Julian) to  10.4.2024 is not 300 years.  300 years is at 21.4.2024.

In what analytical frameworks is the correctness of the math important? What problems will it help me to solve?    Will the errors introduced be greater than the confidence interval around most historical dates?  Arithmetic is easy, but math can be manipulated to give whatever answers you need.

@MCW I agree that better option is to use original date, also in that case dates from manuscript/papers correspond to date in history books.

Celebrations or remembrances are a social event. Consider, for instance, Catholic and Eastern Orthodox religious calendars. Or the remembrance of VE day, which is one day later in Russia due to time zones. Ukraine made the deliberate decision to switch to May 8th.
Historians should specify the dating system if that is an issue.

Lets say some book/theory is published 5.8.1724.(Julian), is today  anniversary of book/theory 5.8. or 16.8.(corresponding Gergorian)?

@22flower, depends on your social and cultural expectations. A historican might conclude that the book was likely published on 15-AUG-1724 and that the publisher likely used the Julian calendar at the time. One could then calculate how many days ago that was. But "anniversary" is not hard science.

historians use original Julian date or new Gregorian date for date of discoveries, what is rule or more common?

VE day is celebrated in Russia a day later for a different reason than time difference.

It depends. One obvious example is the October revolution in Russia, which took place on 7-th of November according to Gregorian calendar, but 25-th of October according to the Julian one, in use in Russia at the time.
After switching to Gregorian calendar some holidays were shifted to fall on the correct Gregorian date - notably the New Years day (January 1st) and May Day (May 1st), while religious holidays stuck to the older calendar - the Christmas day falls on January 7th, and there is also discrepancy for the Passover celebrations (but this seems to be more general discrepancy between Catholics and Orthodox Christians, or perhaps even between Catholics and non-Catholics.)
Reading historical texts about this period might be somewhat confusing.
The quoted Wiki article on old and new style dates cites examples of other countries where the switch to Gregorian calendar is relatively recent, and some discrepancies may arise.
There are similar situations with Hebrew calendar and Islamic calendar. E.g., Israeli school year largely adheres to Gregorian calendar, but national holidays (religious and non-religious) are celebrated according to Hebrew calendar. Thus, the Israeli Independence Day, considered to be May 14-th, is celebrated on different Gregorian date every year (although the Hebrew calendar returns to its original place vis-à-vis Gregorian every 17 years.) Palestinians however chose to commemorate the closely related Nakba day according to Gregorian calendar on May 15-th.
Remark
In response to the comments: I don't know, if teher is an established convention in scientific literature. As far as I can judge by the books I read, when narrating a sequence of events or simply trying to place an event in contemporary context ( as in Jan's examples), it is quite common to use the calendar that was in use there and then. When pointing when an event happened in respect to modern reference points or discussing time periods, modern calendar serves the reader better.
As another example, one could mention Yom Kippour War of 1973, also known as October war and Ramadan war. All three terms communicate different information:

Yom Kippour points to the specific day of Hebrew calendar, and is useful in the context of describing how Israel was taken off guard, because this is teh day when the country comes to a standstill. However, the dat may fall anywhere between mid-September and mid-November.
October war is precise and impartial designation of when the war took place (6-25 October 1973.)
Ramadan war provides political and religious context as seen from the Arab side - Ramadan is the month of great victories... but it may occur in Spring just as well as in Autumn.


historians use original Julian date or new Gregorian date for date of discoveries, what is rule or more common?

@22flower It is quite common to use the calendar in use at that place and at that time. Think Ides of March, or "fifth year of Kangxis reign" etc
